# how to track paypal transaction in google analytics

Tags: paypal, google-analytics, tracking

I want to track my conversions coming from Paypal checkout option. 
I want to differentiate between conversions from normal checkout process & conversions from Paypal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about Google analytics tracking of PayPal and is not programing related.

Answer (score -1):

on the newest Paypal javascript API, this is how to log:

```
    paypal.Button.render({
...
        payment: function(data, actions) {
            return new paypal.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                // LOG BUTTON CLICKED
                resolve();
            }).then(function () {
                return actions.payment.create({
                  ..
                });
            });
        },

      onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

            return actions.payment.get().then(function(paymentDetails) {
...
                    return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                    // LOG FINISHED TRANSACTION 
           }})
     },
     // same for onerror, oncancel
```